# Toggling a match in vimrc

Tags: linux, vim, vi

I have the following lines in my vimrc file:

```
hi ExtraWhitespace cterm=NONE ctermbg=green ctermfg=green guibg=green guifg=green
match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$\|\t/
```

These lines will highlight all lines with no characters other than spaces as well as any tab.
I would like to add a function that will toggle highlighting the whitespace.

```
map <F8> :call ToggleWhitespaceMatching()<cr>
```

I have tried to write my own, but have not been able to get it working.  Could someone please suggest a function to accomplish this.  Also, i would like the matching to be on, by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar idea to kev's but toggles the hilighting instead of the match

```
let s:hilightws = 1

hi ExtraWhitespace cterm=NONE ctermbg=green ctermfg=green guibg=green guifg=green
hi link MaybeExtraWhitespace ExtraWhitespace
match MaybeExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/    

fun ToggleWhitespaceMatching()
  if s:hilightws
    hi link MaybeExtraWhitespace NONE
    let s:hilightws = 0
  else
    hi link MaybeExtraWhitespace ExtraWhitespace
    let s:hilightws = 1
  endif
endfun

map <F8> :call ToggleWhitespaceMatching()<CR>
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you both...  I went with this version because I like the idea of toggling highlighting only.